# Local WordPress Development With Docker and Cron

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, cron, dockerfile

I use Docker for local WordPress development, currently I'm on a project I need to setup some cron jobs to automate content import. The imports are created by a WordPress plugin but I need a `cron` service to call them

This is my docker compose file so far:

```docker
version: '2'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    volumes:
      - ./db/:/var/lib/mysql/
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    build: ./docker/wordpress
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
      - ./themes/:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/
      - ./plugins/:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/
      - ./uploads/:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: wp_
  scheduling:
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    build:
      context: ./docker/scheduling
      network: host
    volumes:
      - ./cron-logs/:/var/log/
```

As you can see I have three services, `mysql`, `wordpress` and the `scheduling` one, here I have setup a basic cron

```docker
# File: Dockerfile
FROM php:7.4.8-fpm-alpine

# Copy project-cron file to the cron.d directory
COPY project-cron /etc/cron.d/cron
 
# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cron

# Apply cron job
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/cron
 
# Link cron log file to stdout
RUN ln -s /dev/stdout /var/log/cron
 
# Run the command on container startup
CMD ["crond", "-f", "-l", "8"]
```

The project cron looks as follows:

```cmd
# must be ended with a new line "LF" (Unix) and not "CRLF" (Windows)
* * * * * echo "Current date is `date`" > /var/log/cron
*/5 * * * * wget -q -O - "http://localhost/wp-load.php?import_key=SMw2F9f&import_id=4&action=trigger"
* * * * * wget -q -O - "http://localhost/wp-load.php?import_key=SMw2F9f&import_id=4&action=processing"
# An empty line is required at the end of this file for a valid cron file.
```

This all works once started, the problem comes with the `wget` requests, I'm always getting

```terminal
wget: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused
```

Is there a way the `scheduling` service uses the localhost from the `wordpress` service?
Do I need to setup a domain? How can I make the calls to localhost from `schedueling` work?

Answer (score 2):

After struggling for some days I found out you can use `host.docker.internal` as an alias for localhost, please note this is a local development solution and not ready for production but using the crons like this:

```terminal
# must be ended with a new line "LF" (Unix) and not "CRLF" (Windows)
* * * * * echo "Current date is `date`" > /var/log/cron
*/5 * * * * wget -q -O - "http://host.docker.internal/wp-load.php?import_key=SMw2F9f&import_id=4&action=trigger"
* * * * * wget -q -O - "http://host.docker.internal/wp-load.php?import_key=SMw2F9f&import_id=4&action=processing"
# An empty line is required at the end of this file for a valid cron file.
```

Worked